# Sound buttons not working in KDE

Tags: sound, kde

Sound is working perfectly under Unity. When I login to KDE, the sound buttons stop working. I have an HP Envy laptop, f6, f7, f8 are supposed to mute the sound and change the volume. When I click them I get the usual animation with the sound bar on the screen but nothing happens, the sound stays the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

hey  i also get same problem as you get.
 i dnt get pop up sound when volume is turn on

Solution
(i did )

1. you can right click sound logo in between scissor and battery
2. select the master channel
3. there are two choice for you

   - built-in-audio streo (HDMI)
   - built-in-audio stereo

just simply choose built-in-audio stereo (also make sure you have choice playback devices in "CURRENT MIXER")

i hope this help you! cheers  mate

Comment: This worked for me on a Lenovo ThinkPad T540p. I faced the same problem after my last system update.

Comment: This worked for me on Lenovo ThinkPad T400 but I first had to install kmix via terminal with sudo apt-get install kmix after which I ran kmix and I got the volume indicator, the steps mentioned on this answer did the rest. Thank you very much!